# DNS for a server in a data centre

Tags: dns

I have a couple of servers I have been running at home for a while now but I am looking to move them into a proper server environment. They currently get their internet access from my router provided by my ISP.

As I understand it they router gets the DNS address from my ISP which allows my computer and servers to access websites by their address.

If I move my servers into a data center and they each get their own WAN IP address how would I go about assigning a DNS to them? Would I need to create my own etc.?

Comment: Thanks. I do understand how DNS works, I just was not sure how to implement it or if I even needed to :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have too, numerous organisations have these for free. I always use the ones of google found at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. Read more at https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question to mean how you can assign a DNS name to your servers so that they can be accessed by name on the internet.  As you suspected, you'll first need to register a domain name.  From there, your registrar will ask you where you'd like to host DNS for your new domain.  Some registrars will do this for you for free.  Then, you'll give each host a name and assign it an A record corresponding to the IP of the server.  From then on, you'll be able to access your hosts via that domain name instead of just by IP.

Answer (score 0):

Some data centers will provide you with local resolvers (that's the part of dns you are calling "dns server") to use just like your home/office ISP does.

If you need more control over the dns system and/or more performance (eg. because you have a mail filtering systems hammering DNS with requests for RBL and such) you could install your own caching resolver on one or more of your systems and use that.